# Browser doesn't show tab "raw | parsed", when i send json object by Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running the express server by node, and i saw many sites, when you open json object in those sites by browser, you see tab "raw | parsed" in right corner, can you tell me, how to switch on this option?
My code:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Weather</h1>')
})

app.get('/help', (req, res) => {
    res.send([{
        name: 'Andrew'
    }, {
        name: 'Sarah'
    }])
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>About</h1>')
})

app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        forecast: 'It is snowing',
        location: 'Philadelphia'
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port 3000.')
})
```

Comment: Try `res.json(yourObject);`

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you are using Chrome you need this extension.
[json formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa)

Firefox comes with that feature already installed.